# Is there any way to make a stroke gradient with blurish effect in Android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-gradient-drawable

The design I received from the designer is something like this, but I'm not able to build this just using **layer-list**.
Is there any way to achieve this UI? It will really helpful for me as well as other fellow developers!

Thanks :)[image: Item Image]

Answer (score 0):

looks like job for custom [`onDraw`](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing) method or at least [9-patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch). you won't achieve blur effect with `layer-list`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Can you share an example or blog on this one?

Comment: sadly, I don't have any... use linked official articles as a hook, you will find more about these topics and examples. I would advice you to start with 9-patch, but that depends on how you want to use this drawable (like custom `CardView`?)